# How to pass two differents bash files in docker run entrypoint

Tags: docker

Dear members of support,
I am trying to override the entrypoint using the flag entrypoint. I need to execute sequentially two files /usr/share/logstash/config/start.sh and /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint. How can I do that? I am trying

```
docker run --entrypoint /usr/share/logstash/config/start.sh && /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint  --rm -it -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="xxxxx" -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="ccc/xx"  xxx
```

without success. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Are you trying to launch a background process in a container, before the main container process?  It's generally better to try to launch this in a separate container.

Answer (score 1):

`--entrypoint <string>` expects an executable to run, you've supplied a bit of shell code.

One way is to utilize the json syntax for `--entrypoint` to run a shell which does your expected work.  Here's a small example:

```sh
$ docker run -ti --entrypoint '["bash", "-c", "echo hi && exec bash"]' ubuntu:focal -c echo foo
hi
root@38209f44c079:/# exit
```

adjusting to your entrypoint:

```sh
--entrypoint '["bash", "-c", "/usr/share/logstash/config/start.sh && exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint"]' ...
```